# Regular Expression first 2 characters either alphabetic or numeric but not combination of both

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression in PHP to validate a string like: "AB345678" or "12345678". That is, Eight(8) letter string containing first 2 letters as alphabetic or numeric, but not the combination of both, and then the remaining 6 letters numeric.
I tried to do it by my own but it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}$/
```

I'm new to Regex hence need help here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this

```
^([a-zA-Z]{2}|\d{2})\d{6}$
```

Comment: This does not satisfy the OP's desire. He wants the last six character numeric only.

Comment: You don't need a lookbehind for this, he doesn't need the prefix excluded from the match.

Comment: I would suggest using a non-capturing group as you do not need to result of the capture group. `(?:[a-zA-Z]{2}|\d{2})`.

Comment: @bmorris591: It really means nothing if it's the only capture group, he either uses it or not.

Comment: @bmorris591 yes you are right..he doesn't need it but as Madara said it doesn't really matter..

Comment: That depends what you mean by 'nothing'. It makes the regex's intent clear - it shows to a reader of the code that that match group is not used. It is also a little faster.

Answer (score 2):

Use `|` (aka alternation operator or pipe operator) to say 'either the left hand side OR the right hand side':

`/^([0-9]{2}|[a-zA-Z]{2})[0-9]{6}$/`

Comment: Hi Patashu,
Thanks for quick reply.
Your solution worked like charm. :)

Comment: I would suggest using a non-capturing group as you do not need to result of the capture group. `(?:[0-9]{2}|[a-zA-Z]{2})`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^ \d{8} | (?: [a-zA-Z]{2} \d{6} ) $ /x
```

Comment: Format your code! Please expand on your answer, code only answers are not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be unicode compatible:

```
^(?:\pL{2}|\pN{2})\pN{6}$
```

with php:

```
if (preg_match('/^(?:\pL{2}|\pN{2})\pN{6}$/u', $string)) {
    echo "OK";
}
```

- `\pL` stands for any letter.
- `\pN` stands for any number.